# Distribute wxWidgets applications on Linux platforms

Tags: linux, wxwidgets, software-distribution

I started to learn wxWidgets some days ago and I found it really good, but when I tried to "export" it to another platform, it didn't work. I expected that, but when I searched how to distribute wxWidgets apps, I didn't find that much, except to install all the wxWidgets library on that platform.

I use Debian 10, while the other platform where I need to export my app uses Lubuntu. It says that it needs a wxgtk3.0 library, but I guess that library will need even more libraries.

How do I export my wxWidgets application **without** asking the user to manually install and build all the library on its platform? Maybe even using .deb package (if really needed). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please understand that every single distribution uses it own format comparing to Windows where there is an Installation Wizard or OSX where there is a Bundle.

Now, you can create a deb file where you set everything up.

So you can create an rpm  (which is basically the same thing as deb, just for different distribution).

This is the best way as it ensures that all dependencies and their versions are satisfied.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Many Linux distributions have wxWidgets packages, so one possibility would be to simply ask users to install these packages when they need to use your application. This is not really different from installing GTK libraries or even X11 (or Wayland) that your application also depends on -- the only difference is that these libraries are almost surely already installed on any Linux desktop system, while wxWidgets ones might not be.

Another alternative is to link your application statically with wxWidgets libraries. This will make it much bigger and will prevent the users from upgrading the libraries on their system to improve the application behaviour, but can be simpler for the users to install. Note that if you choose the static linking route, you typically need to build your application on the oldest distribution you want to support (which is probably *not* Debian 10, which is relatively recent), as this is a simple way to ensure that it doesn't require newer versions of the (other, non-wx) libraries than the ones already present on the user's system.

Comment: Could you show me some of these packages? I make fairly simple wx applications so  maybe I don't need that much of libraries.

Comment: Just search for `wx` or `wxgtk`, e.g. here are [Debian packages](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=wxgtk&searchon=names&suite=stable&section=all) and here are [Ubuntu ones](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=wxgtk).